# Ropsten Testnet Issues? Read here!

Tags: discussion, faq

If you're experiencing trouble getting [ropsten](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ropsten) testnet to work, please read

> [Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/12477/87)

before asking a new question.

Thank you.